# Word for discrimination based on (partly) consisting of mechanical parts

Tags: single-word-requests

There are a lot of words for various types of discrimination. What is the word for discrimination based on (partly) consisting of mechanical parts?

EDIT: Comments ask for clarification so: I mean people who co-consist of a pacemaker or mechanical eye or limb, or creatures that mostly consist of mechanical parts.

Comment: I doubt there are any *specific* terms, but (a) What do you mean by "discrimination"?, and (b) What do you mean by "mechanical parts"? If border security staff suspect a guy with a pacemaker might actually be a suicide bomber carrying "self-embedded" explosives, that's kinda different to a woman not fancying a guy with a glass eye.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, if you want a real-life example which contains answers to both your questions, have a look at the article I linked to at the very bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Dan: Would it not be better to wait until OP has answered my "clarifying" questions before posting an answer based on your assumptions as to what he's asking about?

Comment: Perhaps, but there's a trade-off: new users, not understanding the process here, often seek immediate answers, and not getting them, frequently abandon their questions (rather than clarify their meaning). Meaning we're left with a orphaned question. Alternatively, we can post answers based on our best *current* understanding of the question, which may attract their attention; if it later turns out we answered the wrong question, or answered incorrectly, we can either edit or delete our answers. This is the course I chose (not least because this I'm fairly confident in my interpretation).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Your pacemaker example is the correct one.

Comment: @Jop: So you're talking about "official" discrimination, not the straightforward "yuck factor" that you might feel when having sex with a person having a non-removable mechanical arm, for example (if there's any such thing, which as yet I kinda doubt). I suspect there aren't yet many/any real-world contexts where such discrimination might apply, and that you're really asking about a possible future where we argue about whether sentient robots are entitled to "basic human rights".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes; that was my interpretation and the thrust of my answer.

Comment: @Dan: I think your answer - and indeed most speculation about this (possible?, future?) prejudice - is more focussed on *"non-biological **consciousness**"* and the possibility of technologically-enhanced humans (ordinary people's fear of ultra-powerful cyborgs, ultra-smart robots, etc.). That's not necessarily the same thing as official discrimination against disabled people who need "mechanical" prostheses simply to give them something approaching the physical capabilities of "normal" people.

Comment: the simple fact is **THIS QUESTION SHOULD BE EDITED AND CLEARED-UP**.  Nobody has a clue what you're talking about dude!

Comment: "Your pacemaker example is the correct one" ... the edit button is directly under the question, go for it!

Comment: @FumbleFingers, if you click through some of my links, you'll find the prejudice is specifically directed against ***physically** augmented or modified humans*; the key driver being the repugnance at "messing with nature" or the fear of being out-competed by enhanced *bodies*.

Comment: @Dan: I don't want to start **SHOUTING**, but I agree with Joe on this one.

Comment: Jop, the word "luddite" might be useful to you in this type of thing, maybe

Answer (score 4):

Usage on this really hasn't gelled yet, and the field is still wide open for a really good coining (like Joe's *cyphobe*, which I love).

That said, if we restrict ourselves to *established* terms, currently the most popular is "***biost***" (*bio* for "life", specifically *natural* life + *ist*, modeled upon *racism*, *sexism*, *ageism*, *speciesism* etc).

For example, the [TV Tropes article No Transhumanism Allowed](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoTranshumanismAllowed) describes exactly this bias:

> prejudice against non-biological consciousness or modified life, sometimes called ***bioism***

Though as I mentioned, usage really hasn't gelled yet, and, for example, Orion's Arm, the transhumanist encyclopedia (and erstwhile online epicenter of transhumanist thought) reserves *bioist* and *bioism* for [a follower of] a kind of nature-worshipping religion (think modern environmentalism turned up to an 11).

So and instead, they use [***biochauvinism***](http://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/460d983f5f700) (and sometimes ***bioprimism***) for:

> the prejudice that biological systems have an intrinsic superiority

Even given OA's primacy  in the transhumanist arena, I still prefer the term "bioist", because it has a *negative* sense of being *anti*-mechanical, whereas *biochauvanism* has the thrust of being *pro*-organic.

That said, history has amply demonstrated the correlation between the concepts of "pro-me" and "anti-you", so if you're satisfied with the concept of "pro-human", you might ultimately prefer a word with that has a longer pedigree and better recognition.  Try [***anthropism***](http://libcom.org/library/anthropism):

> One of the main supports of the reactionary system is what we may call "**anthropism**". I designate by this term that powerful and world-wide group of erroneous opinions which opposes the human organism to the whole of the rest of nature, and represents it as the preordained end of organic creation

---

By the way, to forestall claims that this is speculative English, please note that [bioism is a real-life problem](http://knowledgenuts.com/2013/11/08/anti-cyborg-discrimination-is-a-terrifyingly-real-thing/) (though at the moment, thankfully, a rare one).

Comment: what about borgphbia or cyborgphobia

Comment: I guess it's worth pointing out that in the *Star Wars* universe, this prejudice called "**Anti-droid sentiment**", which applies mostly to full robots (droids) but also causes suspicion and hatred of cyborgs (mostly organic but partially mechanical people): http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anti-droid_sentiment

Comment: @JoeBlow: I *really* like that. As I said, this is an open field for a really good coining.

Comment: I need to drink more, more often!  :)  I'm sure someone's used those before.  You know, anything that makes me think of 7 of 9, is good by me...

Comment: I think Seven would be *much* cuter without the implants. Hmm, is that biochauvinistic of me? :)

Comment: Hey you know what I'd use if I was writing a dystopian novel.  "cyphobe".  So, if it was a YA dystopian novel: "Her t-shirt had never looked so tight as she reached to her locker. But I knew her parents were real cyphobe assholes, and I couldn't exactly hide my carbon fiber right arm..."

Comment: *mind blown gesture*

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use "cyphobe" which I just coined.

Answer (score 1):

If you're more concerned with a fear, revulsion, or prejudice against people with *prosthetic body parts* in the *modern* world (as opposed to the speculative *future* animus against *augmented humanity*), and novel coinings are acceptable, can I suggest:

> ***prosthesisophobia***

The closest "real" (ie historically attested) word with a related meaning is, as far as I can tell:

> ***apotemnophobia*** (rarely **acrotomophobia**):  fear of amputation or amputees (persons with amputations)